# Multiple replace - using sed or awk

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a code snippet like below

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
  ID integer NOT NULL,
  ROW_CREATED varchar (26) NULL,
  BATCH_LOG_ID integer NULL,
  TRANSACTION_TYPE varchar(5) NULL,
  PARTITION_COL integer NOT NULL
) ON BASE_PARTITION (PARTITION_COL);
```

I want to change the code like below

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
  ID integer NOT NULL,
  ROW_CREATED varchar (26) NULL,
  BATCH_LOG_ID integer NULL,
  TRANSACTION_TYPE varchar(5) NULL
) PARTITIONED BY (PARTITION_COL integer NOT NULL);
```

Can this be done using a sed or awk?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to change the DDL. There is a column on which partition defined PARTITION_COL integer NOT NULL. In the new DDL that column shouldn't be there in the column list rather it should come within the PARTITIONED BY clause

Comment: This will also work for me if I can get a series of commands which I can put in a script

Answer (score 0):

```
'BEGIN{f=0} ; { if ($0 ~ "TRANSACTION_TYPE varchar\\(5\\) NULL,") { print ; printf("%-s", ") PARTITIONED BY (PARTITION_COL integer NOT NULL);") ; f=1 } else if (f==0) print }' inputfile
```

This will print the lines of the input file until it reaches the line with "varchar(5)" in it, where it prints that line followed by the new "PARTITIONED BY" line.